# Amazon MWS Read Inventory Stock Php

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I am trying to get the available stock of a product for an sku. I searched it a-lot found some pdfs non of them worked for me. I am stuck scratching my head what to do, can anyone help me I will be more then thankful.
I also tried this code,

```
$skus = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_SellerSkuList();
$skus->setmember( 'sku-111' );

invokeListInventorySupply($service, $request->withSellerSkus( $skus ) );
```

but what it returned is InStockSupplyQuantity is 0 you can see on this [link](http://ht.dnsuk.net/amazon/FBAInventoryServiceMWS/Samples/ListInventorySupplySample.php)

This is the full version of the code that I am using,

```
<?php

include_once ('.config.inc.php'); 

$config = array (
  'ServiceURL' => MWS_ENDPOINT_URL,
  'ProxyHost' => null,
  'ProxyPort' => -1,
  'MaxErrorRetry' => 3
);

 $service = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Client(
     ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
     SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
     $config,
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     APPLICATION_VERSION);

 $request = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_ListInventorySupplyRequest();
  $request->setSellerId(SELLER_ID);

    $skus = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_SellerSkuList();
    $skus->setmember( 'sku-111' );

  invokeListInventorySupply($service, $request->withSellerSkus( $skus ) );

  function invokeListInventorySupply(FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Interface $service, $request) 
  {
      try {
              $response = $service->listInventorySupply($request);

                echo ("Service Response<br />");
                echo ("=============================================================================<br />");

                echo("        ListInventorySupplyResponse<br />");
                if ($response->isSetListInventorySupplyResult()) { 
                    echo("            ListInventorySupplyResult<br />");
                    $listInventorySupplyResult = $response->getListInventorySupplyResult();
                    if ($listInventorySupplyResult->isSetInventorySupplyList()) { 
                        echo("                InventorySupplyList<br />");
                        $inventorySupplyList = $listInventorySupplyResult->getInventorySupplyList();
                        $memberList = $inventorySupplyList->getmember();
                        foreach ($memberList as $member) {
                            echo("                    member<br />");
                            echo ("=============================================================================<br />");
                            if ($member->isSetSellerSKU()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        SellerSKU<br />");
                                echo("                            " . $member->getSellerSKU() . "<br /><br />");
                            }
                            if ($member->isSetFNSKU()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        FNSKU<br />");
                                echo("                            " . $member->getFNSKU() . "<br /><br />");
                            }
                            if ($member->isSetASIN()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        ASIN<br />");
                                echo("                            " . $member->getASIN() . "<br /><br />");
                            }
                            if ($member->isSetCondition()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        Condition<br />");
                                echo("                            " . $member->getCondition() . "<br /><br />");
                            }
                            if ($member->isSetTotalSupplyQuantity()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        TotalSupplyQuantity<br />");
                                echo("                            " . $member->getTotalSupplyQuantity() . "<br /><br />");
                            }
                            if ($member->isSetInStockSupplyQuantity()) 
                            {
                                echo("                        InStockSupplyQuantity<br />");
                                echo("                            " . $member->getInStockSupplyQuantity() . "<br /><br />");
                            }
                            if ($member->isSetEarliestAvailability()) { 
                                echo("                        EarliestAvailability<br />");
                                $earliestAvailability = $member->getEarliestAvailability();
                                if ($earliestAvailability->isSetTimepointType()) 
                                {
                                    echo("                            TimepointType<br />");
                                    echo("                                " . $earliestAvailability->getTimepointType() . "<br /><br />");
                                }
                                if ($earliestAvailability->isSetDateTime()) 
                                {
                                    echo("                            DateTime<br />");
                                    echo("                                " . $earliestAvailability->getDateTime() . "<br /><br />");
                                }
                            } 
                            if ($member->isSetSupplyDetail()) { 
                                echo("                        SupplyDetail<br />");
                                $supplyDetail = $member->getSupplyDetail();
                                $member1List = $supplyDetail->getmember();
                                foreach ($member1List as $member1) {
                                    echo("                            member<br />");
                                    if ($member1->isSetQuantity()) 
                                    {
                                        echo("                                Quantity<br />");
                                        echo("                                    " . $member1->getQuantity() . "<br /><br />");
                                    }
                                    if ($member1->isSetSupplyType()) 
                                    {
                                        echo("                                SupplyType<br />");
                                        echo("                                    " . $member1->getSupplyType() . "<br /><br />");
                                    }
                                    if ($member1->isSetEarliestAvailableToPick()) { 
                                        echo("                                EarliestAvailableToPick<br />");
                                        $earliestAvailableToPick = $member1->getEarliestAvailableToPick();
                                        if ($earliestAvailableToPick->isSetTimepointType()) 
                                        {
                                            echo("                                    TimepointType<br />");
                                            echo("                                        " . $earliestAvailableToPick->getTimepointType() . "<br /><br />");
                                        }
                                        if ($earliestAvailableToPick->isSetDateTime()) 
                                        {
                                            echo("                                    DateTime<br />");
                                            echo("                                        " . $earliestAvailableToPick->getDateTime() . "<br /><br />");
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    if ($member1->isSetLatestAvailableToPick()) { 
                                        echo("                                LatestAvailableToPick<br />");
                                        $latestAvailableToPick = $member1->getLatestAvailableToPick();
                                        if ($latestAvailableToPick->isSetTimepointType()) 
                                        {
                                            echo("                                    TimepointType<br />");
                                            echo("                                        " . $latestAvailableToPick->getTimepointType() . "<br /><br />");
                                        }
                                        if ($latestAvailableToPick->isSetDateTime()) 
                                        {
                                            echo("                                    DateTime<br />");
                                            echo("                                        " . $latestAvailableToPick->getDateTime() . "<br /><br />");
                                        }
                                    } 
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    } 
                    if ($listInventorySupplyResult->isSetNextToken()) 
                    {
                        echo("                NextToken<br />");
                        echo("                    " . $listInventorySupplyResult->getNextToken() . "<br /><br />");
                    }
                } 
                if ($response->isSetResponseMetadata()) { 
                    echo("            ResponseMetadata<br />");
                    $responseMetadata = $response->getResponseMetadata();
                    if ($responseMetadata->isSetRequestId()) 
                    {
                        echo("                RequestId<br />");
                        echo("                    " . $responseMetadata->getRequestId() . "<br /><br />");
                    }
                } 

     } catch (FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Exception $ex) {
         echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "<br /><br />");
         echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "<br /><br />");
         echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "<br /><br />");
         echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "<br /><br />");
         echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "<br /><br />");
         echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "<br /><br />");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

This code works fine for me:

```
...
$skus= new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_SellerSkuList();
$skus->setmember("??-????-????"); // Your SKU
$request = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_ListInventorySupplyRequest();
$request->setSellerId(SELLER_ID);
$request->setMarketplace(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$request->setSellerSkus($skus);
invokeListInventorySupply($service, $request);
...
```

My complete code is based on the file `\src\FBAInventoryServiceMWS\Samples\ListInventorySupplySample.php` from the [PHP Client Library v20101001](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?group=fba&section=inventory&version=v20101001) where the code above replace the line 71.

The output looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

--Edit--

being that PHP and I are not the best of friends I'm going to paraphrase the steps needed to ensure that you can get the data you want:

1. build your request with ListInventorySupply
2. crawl your response looking by looking at the following XML and ensuring your calling the objects correctly:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <ListInventorySupplyResponse  xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentInventory/2010-10-01">
   <ListInventorySupplyResult>
       <InventorySupplyList>
            <member>
                 <SellerSKU>SampleSKU1</SellerSKU>
                 <ASIN>B00000K3CQ</ASIN>
                 <TotalSupplyQuantity>20</TotalSupplyQuantity>
                 <FNSKU>X0000000FM</FNSKU>
                 <Condition>NewItem</Condition>
                 <SupplyDetail/>
                 <InStockSupplyQuantity>15</InStockSupplyQuantity>
                 <EarliestAvailability>
                     <TimepointType>Immediately</TimepointType>
                 </EarliestAvailability>
            ....
   ```
3. In C# each reponse is available through a set of objects, for instance:

   ```
   submitFeedResponse.SubmitFeedResult.FeedSubmissionInfo.FeedType
   ```

   or

   ```
   submitFeedResponse.ResponseMetadata.RequestId
   ```

I have found most of my invalid responses have been a result of not having the proper objects being called, or if I did the have the correct object, I was not displaying it correctly ( not calling toString() for example ).

On the other hand, you are returning your sku name, so have you ensured that the sku you are using should be returning an actual quantity via seller central?

Alternatively some excellent support is available at:

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=35

Comment: I tried enough examples but none of them is working for me. I have edited my question to post all you need thanks.

Comment: What this will do is it will add the new item what I want is to read the inventory I don't want to write.

Comment: Being that your sample is the MWS php sample, have you ensured the entire API is located on your webserver, including the mock( if you want to run mock samples like this one ) and the Model directories?