# Amazon MWS Inventory (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have a problem with the Amazon MWS Inventory (ListInventorySupplySample.php).

I testet my account data with the scratchpad, it works fine.

Id like with the following code the inventory of a specific SKU.

```
     $skus = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_SellerSkuList();

     $skus->setmember("SKU");


     $request = new FBAInventoryServiceMWS_Model_ListInventorySupplyRequest();

     $request->setSellerId(SELLER_ID);

     $request->setSellerSkus($skus);


     invokeListInventorySupply($service, $request);
```

Output:

```
    ListInventorySupplyResponse ListInventorySupplyResult InventorySupplyList member SellerSKU string FNSKU string ASIN string Condition string TotalSupplyQuantity 100 InStockSupplyQuantity 100 EarliestAvailability TimepointType string DateTime 2008-09-29T01:49:45 SupplyDetail member Quantity 100 SupplyType string EarliestAvailableToPick TimepointType string DateTime 2014-09-18T23:18:33 LatestAvailableToPick TimepointType string DateTime 2006-08-19T17:27:14+00:00 NextToken string ResponseMetadata RequestId string
```

Who can help me, with this problem?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So you have a problem. I'd suggest telling us what it is.

Comment: The quantity ist wrong and the SellerSKU, ASIN are empty.

Comment: looks like you were hitting the mock api interface; probably need to comment out the second instance of `$service =`

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are not connected with Production.

Are you using

```
$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Mock()
```

Please use and comment out Mock service object.

```
$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
     $config,
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     APPLICATION_VERSION);
```

Another post explaining your issue.

[Amazon MWS Read Inventory Stock Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401212/amazon-mws-read-inventory-stock-php)

Thanks.